# Solace .Net API compiled for AnyCPU

Tags: solace, anycpu

Why isn't Solace .Net API targeting AnyCPU? I've compared both **SolaceSystems.Solclient.Messaging.dll** and **SolaceSystems.Solclient.Messaging_64.dll** assemblies in Reflector and they are absolutely identical except for one class `SolaceNativeAPI` which points to **libsolclient.dll** and **libsolclient_64.dll**. It seems it would be very easy to convert this class to a non-static, expose common interface `ISolaceNativeAPI` which would be used instead of `SolaceNativeAPI` and create a factory that checks current process architecture and returns 32 or 64 bit implementation.

I'd be happy to submit a pull request if Solace code repository was public because it'd make my current work easier.

Answer (score 5):

The Solace .NET API does not currently have an 'Any CPU' .NET binary because it was found in the past to slightly degrade performance. The Solace .NET API makes use of a native adapter layer that wraps a native library. To achieve run-time selection of the correct native library (32 or 64-bit) we need to introduce an indirection layer between the .NET API and the native adapter. This was tested in the past but found it degraded API performance by 5% to 10%, which was deemed too high to be released.